# ATtiny Arduino as ISP AVRDude flash command

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude, attiny

I recently bought a couple of ATtiny85 chips and have been using my Arduino UNO as an ISP Programmer to flash them from the Arduino IDE.

Now I want ot flash some code made in Ateml Studio onto the chip.

I tried `C:\>avrdude -c arduino -p attiny85 -P com9 -U flash:w:/path/to/code.hex:i`, however it will allways tell me that it expected another device signature and fails when it tries to verify the code on the board after uploading it.

As suggested by a fried, I tried `-b 19200 -c avrisp -F -V`, but it will still not run the code after uploading the file.

**Is there a way to find out which command the arduino IDE executes when I press the play button, since it works perfectly this way.**

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post an external URL as my main answer, but the process is a bit involved.  First you need to hook up everything just right, put a crystal on the 85 chip, etc, get it breadboarded, then you have a starting point

Try the procedure outlined [here](https://app.box.com/s/ol1z8jjnrpy6wly4w61imt7wcbxk3fcg).